# The current path, post/1/{% url 'post_edit' post.pk}, didn't match any of these

Tags: django, django-urls

I am learning Django and am currently trying to use a button to edit a form. I bought a book and coded exactly what the book says and even copied and pasted the code from the author's github and it still doesn't work. I get the error "The current path, post/1/{% url 'post_edit' post.pk}, didn't match any of these."

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    BlogListView,
    BlogUpdateView,
    BlogDetailView,
    BlogCreateView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', BlogUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_edit'),
    path('post/new/', BlogCreateView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('', BlogListView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

I am expecting this to open a page to edit a form of a blog that was posted.

Comment: Please post the html link you are using to navigate to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have make some mistake in near `{% url 'post_edit' post.pk}`.
It should be something like `{% url 'post_edit' post.pk %}`

`{%  %}` - when text is surrounded by these delimiters, it means that there is some special function or code running, and the result of that will be placed here.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought this was the problem, but I couldn't find where I had left this out at. I went back and found the error after your comment.